# Method chaining in python and how to have access to the entire string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to add a basic class that does some method chaining in a sql/pandas-like way. Something like:

```
ResultSet.filter(...).exclude(...).sort(...)
```

I've done some methods like this before and it's pretty straightforward, as I'll just return `self` at the end.

However, I want to also be able to introspect the entire method-chaining-sequence as occasionally I will have to do things differently if a following/preceding method performs a certain action. So basically, I want to have access to the entire `"ResultSet.filter(...).exclude(...).sort(...)"` as a string saved somewhere.

It's almost like I would need a `prepare` method that stores the string of the entire 'statement' and then the actual execution methods `filter`, `exclude`, etc. Perhaps the easiest way might just be to add in an `.execute()` or `.commit()` method at the end which builds the context and then evaluates everything.

How could this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "saved somewhere"? Saved in memory or in a disk? Also, there is nothing wrong with your approach of building context at the end. If you could mention why you need the chaining sequence, it would be great.

Comment: The object methods `filter(...)`, `exclude(...)`, `sort(...)`, etc. could each append its method name and `*args` to an operation-chain list. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Vishnudev I just mean saved to the instance context. Something like `self.statement_str = "ResultSet.filter(...).exclude(...).sort(...)"`.

Comment: @Jerry101 yea, exactly.

Comment: Why don't you create a stored procedure?

Comment: @Vishnudev this has nothing to do with database calls. This is for something local to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach logs the operations:

```py
class ResultSet:
  def __init__(self):
    self.operation_sequence = []

  def filter(self, *args):
    self.operation_sequence.append(('filter', args))
    ... filter work ...
    return self

  def exclude(self, *args):
    self.operation_sequence.append(('exclude', args))
    ... exclude work ...
    return self

  def sort(self, *args):
    self.operation_sequence.append(('sort', args))
    ... sort work ...
    return self

  @property
  def sequence(self):
    return self.operation_sequence  # reformat the data as desired
```

This approach accumulates deferred operations until the `execute()` method gets called:

```py
class ResultSet:
  def __init__(self):
    self.operation_sequence = []

  def filter(self, *args):
    self.operation_sequence.append(('filter', args))
    return self

  def exclude(self, *args):
    self.operation_sequence.append(('exclude', args))
    return self

  def sort(self, *args):
    self.operation_sequence.append(('sort', args))
    return self

  def execute(self):
    ## TODO: Process the interdependencies then run the operations.
    self.operation_sequence = []
```

If there are many self-logging operations, I'd implement the logging via a decorator or even a metaprogramming technique on method calls.

Comment: if I understand correctly, that would give the method access to all preceding method information but not necessarily the following stuff, correct? How could I defer evaluation until after the entire `operation_sequence` is buitl? Interesting regarding the metaprogramming idea...

Comment: Right. To defer evaluation, make the methods do just the logging part, and add an `execute()` method that goes through the sequence, figures out any interdependencies into local variables or a modified operation sequence, then runs the sequence.